# Solve the system of modular equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I have the system $$2^a \equiv 7 \mod 27 \\2^{18} \equiv 1 \mod 27$$ How can I solve this system?

I was thinking of using Chinese remainder theorem but 27 and 27 are not coprime.

Comment: Repeatedly multiply both sides of the first equation by $2$ until the right side is $1$?

Comment: That's not very efficient @JimmyK4542

Comment: $2^a \equiv 7 \pmod{27} \implies 2^{a+1} \equiv 14 \pmod{27} \implies 2^{a+2} \equiv 28 \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$. That's reasonably efficient. Also, note that the 2nd equation is a true statement, and doesn't have any variables in it. So you are really only solving the first equation.

Comment: It is very strange system of equations since second equation has no variables. So it is either true or false.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I misunderstood. Can  you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $2^{18} \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$, and it is easy to see that $2^k \not\equiv 1 \pmod{27}$ for $1 \le k \le 17$ since none of $2^1 = 2$, $2^2 = 4$, $2^3 = 8$, $2^6 = 64$, $2^9 = 512$ are congruent to $1 \pmod{27}$.

Therefore, $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$ iff $k$ is a multiple of $18$.

Starting from $2^a \equiv 7 \pmod{27}$, we can multiply both sides by $2$ until the right side becomes $1$:

$2^a \equiv 7 \pmod{27} \leadsto 2^{a+1} \equiv 14 \pmod{27} \leadsto 2^{a+2} \equiv 28 \equiv 1 \pmod{27}$

Therefore, $2^a \equiv 7 \pmod{27}$ iff $18 \mid a+2$, i.e. $a \equiv 16 \pmod{18}$.

Answer (score 1):

The group of units of $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$ has ordre $\varphi(p^n)=p^{n-1}(p-1)$. Here, $\mathbf Z/27\mathbf Z$ has order $\varphi(27)=18$. By Lagrange's theorem,  2 has order 1, 3, 9 or 18. As it's not of order 1 nor 3, it has order 9 or 18. So all possible values for $2^a$ are obtained for $0 \le a \le 17$.

Actually we can start computing at $a=5$ since previous values in $\mathbf Z$ are less than $27$. We find successively $2^5 \equiv 5$,  $2^6 \equiv 10 $,  $2^7 \equiv -7 $,  $2^8 \equiv -14$,  $ 2^9 \equiv -1 $ (so $2$ is of order $18$, and it's a generator of the cyclic group $\mathbf Z/27\mathbf Z$).

From these data, we deduce at once that $2^{7+9}\equiv 7$, so that $a=16$.

Comment: In fact, since $2$ is a primitive root modulo $3$ and $2^{3-1}\not \equiv1\pmod9$, it is a primitive root modulo every $3^k$.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I've just found your message and started to read your answer. I was able to grasp it – maybe for young people it's somewhat harsh, due to the two minima, and it's not always immediately clear which is involved – this would explain downvotes perhaps? (b.t.w., I've upvoted).