# Find $a$ such that $83359654581 ... 10843035531 ^ a \equiv 1 \pmod{32003240081}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

> Find $a$ such that
>
> $83359654581036155008716649031639683153293510843035531 ^ a \equiv 1 \pmod{32003240081}$

I am quite familiar with sort of equation like `find m such that m^d = c (mod n)`, but I think it don't help me in this problem since it relative exponent.

I have read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079154/solve-the-system-of-modular-equations), but in my problem, the number is so big.

Comment: What is the source and motivation of this problem?

Comment: Hint: 32003240081= 200009*160009 which are prime.

Comment: Having factored the modulus, you can solve it for each factor.  Then you can take the big number modulo each factor.  Now the numbers aren't so large.

Comment: This is the Discrete logarithm problem you might look up algorithms for solving them.

Comment: Alas, you have accepted the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n = 83359654581036155008716649031639683153293510843035531$.
Let $m = 32003240081$. It has the prime factorization $m = pq$ where $p = 160009, q = 200009$.
One can verify $\gcd(n,p) = \gcd(n,q) = 1$. By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem), we have

$$
\begin{cases}
n^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p\\
n^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
n^\ell \equiv 1 \pmod p\\
n^\ell \equiv 1 \pmod q
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\ell = {\tt lcm}(p-1,q-1)
$$
Together with [Chinese Remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), this leads to
$$n^\ell \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$$
Since we only want an $a$, not the smallest one, $\ell = 
{\tt lcm}(p-1,q-1) = 4000360008$ is a solution.

Comment: -1 **The correct approach is in the other answer** (because generally it is very difficult to factor the modulus - that is the gist of the matter).

Comment: @BillDubuque it is difficult to factor but it is even more difficult to compute factorial. For large $n$, say more than $100$ digits, there are algorithm that can factorize integers faster than the naive bound $O(\sqrt{n})$ but I don't think there are algorithm that can compute $n!$ faster than $O(n)$.

Comment: The question is not about computation. They should have chosen the modulus larger to avoid answers like this (but it was probably large enough for an exam with no access to computers).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Not true: notice that what **JorgeFernándezHidalgo**'s answer says is that any multiple of $\varphi(32003240081)$ is a solution; in particular $\varphi(32003240081)$ itself. But you still need to compute this, so you're back to factoring...

Comment: @AlexM. It seems you have completed missed the key idea. I suggest that you think about it a bit more (in fact there is no need to mention $\phi(k)$ there).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n$ and $k$ are relatively prime. Then $n^{\varphi(k)}\equiv 1 \bmod k$. The same is true if we change $\varphi(k)$ for any multiple of $\varphi(k)$. For example $k!$.

We therefore have that $n^{k!}\equiv 1 \bmod k$ whenever $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

So all you have to do is check that those numbers are relatively prime, you can do that really fast with the euclidean algorithm (on a computer of course).